# cannot instal soundfile in datalab

Tags: python, google-cloud-datalab, libsndfile

i want install sndfile to successfully install another package (musdb), but when I tried following instructions on https://cloud.google.com/datalab/docs/how-to/adding-libraries

```
!pip install sndfile
```

It gives me the following error:

```
{Collecting sndfile
 Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/db/ce/797cacd78490aa9de2e0e119491079d380e2fbbd7a1c5057c9fb2120a643/sndfile-0.2.0.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: cffi>=1.0.0 in /usr/local/envs/py2env/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from sndfile) (1.11.5)
Requirement already satisfied: pycparser in /usr/local/envs/py2env/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from cffi>=1.0.0->sndfile) (2.18)
Building wheels for collected packages: sndfile
Running setup.py bdist_wheel for sndfile ... error
Complete output from command /usr/local/envs/py2env/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-install-NZx2D1/sndfile/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-YWj7At --python-tag cp27:
running bdist_wheel
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/sndfile
copying sndfile/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/sndfile
copying sndfile/build.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/sndfile
copying sndfile/io.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/sndfile
copying sndfile/vio.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/sndfile
copying sndfile/formats.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/sndfile
running build_ext
generating cffi module 'build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/sndfile._sndfile.c'
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7
building 'sndfile._sndfile' extension
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/build
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7
gcc -pthread -B /usr/local/envs/py2env/compiler_compat -Wl,--sysroot=/ -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/usr/local/envs/py2env/include/python2.7 -c 
build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/sndfile._sndfile.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/sndfile._sndfile.o
build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/sndfile._sndfile.c:494:21: fatal error: sndfile.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

---

```
Failed building wheel for sndfile
Running setup.py clean for sndfile
Failed to build sndfile
Installing collected packages: sndfile
Running setup.py install for sndfile ... error
Complete output from command /usr/local/envs/py2env/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-install-NZx2D1/sndfile/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-record-FMQzpS/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
running install
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/sndfile
copying sndfile/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/sndfile
copying sndfile/build.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/sndfile
copying sndfile/io.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/sndfile
copying sndfile/vio.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/sndfile
copying sndfile/formats.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/sndfile
running build_ext
generating cffi module 'build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/sndfile._sndfile.c'
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7
building 'sndfile._sndfile' extension
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/build
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7
gcc -pthread -B /usr/local/envs/py2env/compiler_compat -Wl,--sysroot=/ -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/usr/local/envs/py2env/include/python2.7 -c build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/sndfile._sndfile.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/sndfile._sndfile.o
build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/sndfile._sndfile.c:494:21: fatal error: sndfile.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/local/envs/py2env/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-install-NZx2D1/sndfile/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-record-FMQzpS/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-NZx2D1/sndfile/}
```

I tried to google around, it either suggested to download via conda, which seems difficult with datalab, or with the following command

```
sudo apt-get install libsndfile1
```

which gives me a syntax error in datalab.

---

I need this library since I am trying to import musdb and after installing, when I try to import, it gives me the following error:

```
import musdb

OSErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
```

```
 in <module> .   ()
 ----> 1 import musdb

/usr/local/envs/py2env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/musdb/__init__.py in <module>()
      1 from __future__ import print_function
----> 2 from .audio_classes import Track, Source, Target
      3 from os import path as op
      4 from six.moves import map
      5 import multiprocessing

/usr/local/envs/py2env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/musdb/audio_classes.py in <module>()
      2 from __future__ import division
      3 import os
----> 4 import soundfile as sf
      5 import numpy as np
      6 import stempeg

/usr/local/envs/py2env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/soundfile.py in <module>()
    140     _libname = _find_library('sndfile')
    141     if _libname is None:
--> 142         raise OSError('sndfile library not found')
    143     _snd = _ffi.dlopen(_libname)
    144 except OSError:

OSError: sndfile library not found
```

any insights are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Datalab comes with conda ready to use in Python 2 and 3 environments. This means you should be able to get what you need with the following:

```
%%bash
conda install -y libsndfile ffmpeg
pip install musdb
```